# AngularJS expression why not lazily evaluated, causing "Token 'undefined' not a primary expression"

Tags: angularjs

[This Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yLa1dV) illustrates a "Token 'undefined' not a primary expression" error (visible on Console) during the evaluation of:

```
<div ng-repeat="auimodelField in uimodel.fields" ng-show="!auimodelField.showOnlyIf || {{auimodelField.showOnlyIf}}">
```

My idea/hope was that if there is no auimodelField.showOnlyIf (undefined), it would not continue evaluating as I expected the AngularJS expression evaluation service to have some lazyness, but apparently, in this case, that doesn't work.

Is there a solution to this?  (One possible "workaround" is to always have a showOnlyIf in the model, as in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UaW61d) , of course; but that's kind of a shame.)

Would it be worthwhile to file a bug/enhancement request GitHub issue about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ng-show` with the mixed expression and interpolation seems fishy to me; I would probably go about it a little more explicitly:

```html
<div ng-repeat="auimodelField in uimodel.fields"
  ng-show="shouldShow(auimodelField.showOnlyIf)">
```

```javascript
$scope.shouldShow = function(expr) {
  return !expr || $scope.$eval(expr);
};
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zxx9kW?p=preview

**[Update]**

I did come across this GitHub issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/433 but I believe your issue is that the interpolation is happening first, and the parser is recognizing it as an invalid expression (before it event attempts to run it).

In that case, this should (and does) take care of the problem:

```html
<div ng-repeat="auimodelField in uimodel.fields"
  ng-show="!auimodelField.showOnlyIf || {{auimodelField.showOnlyIf || false}}">
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more why including the || false fixes the problem? I was using ngClass and had the same issue